# How to sort a csv file by column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to sort a .csv file in a very specific way but have pretty limited knowledge of python, i have got some code that works but it doesnt really do exactly what i want it to do, the format is as follows `{header} {header}  {header}  {header}
 {dataA}  {dataB}   {datac}   {dataD}`
In the csv whatever dataA is it is usually repeated 100-200 times, is there a way in which i can get dataA (e.g: examplecompany) and tell me how many times it repeats then how many times dataC repeats with dataA as the first item in the row. for example the output might be  `examplecompany appeared 100 times, out of those 100 datac1 appeared 45 times and datac2 appeared 55` I'm really terrible at explaining things, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share some rows of your data so we get the idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should post an example of the code you have so far. Also, and I don't mean this to be rude, but any spreadsheet editor does the things you ask for by default and Microsoft Excel for example can open CSV files as though they were spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what do you want to accomplish since you have not provided any code or a complete example of input/output for your problem.

For me, it seems that you want to count certain occurrences of data in headerC for each unique data in headerA.

Suppose you have the following .csv file:

```
headerA,headerB,headerC,headerD
examplecompany1,datab,datac1,datad
examplecompany2,datab,datac2,datad
examplecompany2,datab,datac1,datad
examplecompany1,datab,datac2,datad
examplecompany1,datab,datac1,datad
examplecompany2,datab,datac2,datad
examplecompany1,datab,datac1,datad
examplecompany1,datab,datac2,datad
examplecompany1,datab,datac3,datad
```

You can accomplish this counting with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Following is an example of how you might do it.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> df.groupby(['headerA'])['headerC'].value_counts()
headerA          headerC
examplecompany1  datac1     3
                 datac2     2
                 datac3     1
examplecompany2  datac2     2
                 datac1     1
Name: headerC, dtype: int64
```

Here, [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) will group the DataFrame using `headerA` as a reference. You can group by a single Series or a list of Series. After that, the square bracket notation is used to access the `headerC` column and [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) will count each occurrence of `headerC` that was previously grouped by `headerA`. Afterwards you can just format the output for what you want.

Edit:
I forgot that you also wanted to get the number of occurrences of `headerA`, but that is really simple since you can get it directly by selecting the `headerA` column on the `DataFrame df` and call `value_counts` on it.

Comment: What I dislike about this solution is that you need an external library, Pandas.
I was thinking of that solution myself, but I remembered that there already is a builtin dictionary reader that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.DictReader` to read the file and then sort for the key you want.

```
from csv import DictReader

with open("test.csv") as f:
    reader = DictReader(f)
    sorted_rows = sorted(list(reader), key=lambda x: x["column1"])
```

CSV file I tested it with (test.csv):

```
column1,column2
2,bla
1,blubb
```